# Use BeautifulSoup Scrape the photo URL in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

There's no problem with this code. I used it to scrape the photo URLs of other websites, but when I tried to scrape this website, it didn't get any information，I tried to find the actual request address for the website, but I didn't get it

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

for i in range(1, 5000):
    shace=i
    headers = {
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.130 Safari/537.36"}

    url=f'https://xx.knit.bid/en/#/?page={shace}'

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, )

    response.encoding = 'utf-8'
    time.sleep(1)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    for ul in soup.find_all(name='div',attrs={"class":'excerpts'}): 
            div=(ul.find_all(name='article',attrs={"class":'excerpt excerpt-c4'})) 

            hre=[a.get("href")for a in div]
            title=[a.get("title")for a in div]
            dit = {'title': title,'URL': hre,}
            df = pd.DataFrame(dit)
            df.to_csv(r'D:\\88.csv', index=False,mode='a',encoding="utf-8",header=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

website is protected by cloudflare. you have to use selenium to load the website first then parse the HTML. So for that you can use [undetected-chromedriver](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver)

here is a demo code that how you can use. try this demo code.

```
import sys, os
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
import random
from urllib.parse import urljoin

base_url = 'https://xx.knit.bid/'
csv_file = 'data.csv'

def ucdriver():
    try:
        user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
        options = uc.ChromeOptions()

        # Set additional options as in ucdriver
        options.add_argument(f"--user-agent={user_agent}")
        options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
        options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
        options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")  # Bypass OS security model
        options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")  # Overcome limited resource problems
        options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
        options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
        options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
        options.add_argument('--disable-features=PrivacySandboxSettings4') #pop security
        options.add_argument("--window-size=1280,720")
        # options.add_argument("--headless")  # Run Chrome in headless mode
        # options.add_argument(f'user-data-dir={user_data_dir}')

        driver = uc.Chrome(options=options, use_subprocess=True)
        # Initialize the Selenium Chrome driver with the specified options
        # service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        # driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
        return driver

    except Exception as e:
        return None

def main():

    root_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))
    os.chdir(root_path)
    
    driver = ucdriver()
    driver.minimize_window()
    
    for i in range(1, 5000):
        shace=i
        url=f'https://xx.knit.bid/en/#/?page={shace}'
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(random.uniform(1.1, 2.9))
        if driver is None:
            break
        try:
            response = driver.page_source
        except:
            print('Alert Text: Save the child, just turn off the advertising blocking plugin or add this website as a whitelist (。・∀・)ノ')
        soup = bs(response, 'html.parser')
        excerpt = soup.select_one('div.excerpts')
        
        for article in excerpt.select('article.excerpt.excerpt-c4'):
            href = article.select_one('a.imgbox').get('href')
            title = article.select_one('a.imgbox').get('title')
            
            data = {
                'Title' :  title,
                'Link' :  urljoin(base_url, href),
            }
            
            print(data)
    
            df = pd.DataFrame([data])
            df.to_csv(csv_file, mode='a', index=False, header=not os.path.exists(csv_file))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

requirements:

```
attrs==23.2.0
beautifulsoup4==4.12.3
bs4==0.0.2
certifi==2024.2.2
cffi==1.16.0
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
colorama==0.4.6
h11==0.14.0
idna==3.6
numpy==1.26.4
outcome==1.3.0.post0
pandas==2.2.0
pyarrow==15.0.0
pycparser==2.21
pyparsing==3.1.1
PySocks==1.7.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2024.1
requests-toolbelt==1.0.0
selenium==4.17.2
setuptools==69.1.0
six==1.16.0
sniffio==1.3.0
sortedcontainers==2.4.0
soupsieve==2.5
trio==0.24.0
trio-websocket==0.11.1
typing_extensions==4.9.0
tzdata==2024.1
undetected-chromedriver==3.5.5
urllib3==2.2.1
websockets==12.0
wsproto==1.2.0
```

Comment: It looks good, but when I tried to run it, I found that it keeps repeatedly scraping the information from the first page. It cannot scrape to the next page because it needs to slide to the bottom of the webpage to display the next page or click "click to continue loading" to move to the next page,So do I need to simulate mouse clicks?

Comment: you have to scroll to the end first, using javascript, driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")